# CSS Code for landscape (left to right) scrollbar?

Tags: css, scrollbar

I want to make new blog landscape, so that entries read from left to right - I've not been able to find any information by googling, is there a simple code that will take care of this? Thanks

Comment: Any online page where we can see what are you talking about? I mean, i have NO idea what you want.

Comment: Agreed. What you want sounds like a simple CSS solution, HOWEVER, much more information is required to give an accurate answer, otherwise we would just be guessing.

Comment: AFAIU, the OP asks how to create a horizontally scrolling page, instead of the traditional vertical scroller. And that's indeed not all that easy...

Answer (score 2):

The only technique I know of is to set a specific width on a container. Only forced widths will extend beyond the viewport width, everything else gets wrapped.

```
-------------
|  viewport |
| -------------------------
| |      #container       |
| -------------------------
-------------

#container {
    width: 2000px;
}
```

That unfortunately means you'll have to pre-calculate how wide your page needs to be, the content won't dynamically stretch the width the way it does height.

Comment: tables do as well, as you keep adding `td`s ... but that's a whole other topic ;)

Comment: @Gaby Also a good one, but you'll still have to set fixed widths on the <td>s.

Comment: true... you just avoid the pre-calculation of the whole page, but introduce the non-semantic table concept..